# batch "set /p" crashes when no input

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

(I'll use this script as an example)

```
@echo off
:start
cls
set /p x=enter the password:
if %x%==1 goto correct
echo incorrect
timeout 1 >nul /nobreak
goto start
:correct
echo correct
timeout 2 >nul /nobreak
goto start
```

If I just press enter, without any input, it tells me correct.  Why?  how can I prevent this?  Is my syntax incorrect?

Also, If I press space, then enter, the batch file quits.
It tells me in that split second screen the error (something like):

```
Goto was unexpected at this time
```

Which leads me to believe that I didn't give an instance/define the [space] key, but I cut out the spaces in the first instance.  Wouldn't this mean that everything that didn't match the specific criteria

```
if %x%==1 goto correct
```

would just continue on in the script, since it's value didn't meet the one described in the given instance?

Comment: If the user enter space then the line expands to `if  ==1 goto correct` which is a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Common problem - most, but not all of which is solved by

```
if "%x%" EQU "1"...
```

If you are entering a string with a `set/p`, then there's no saying that the data entered doesn't contain <kbd>Spaces</kbd>. The way to get over that is to `"enclose the strings on both sides of the comparison operator in quotes"` - that is, double-quotes `'not single quotes'`

The other problem is more subtle. Pressing just <kbd>Enter</kbd> leave `x` unchanged - it does **not** "set" it to an empty string. Hence, if you start your procedure and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the "contents" of `x` will be indeed be nothing - and the instruction, as has been mentioned, will be resolved to `if ==1 goto correct`, hence the syntax error - and that same syntax error would occur for an entry of spaces.

Suppose you instead enter something - say `2`. `x` is now set to `2`, so the `if` statement is happy and decides to not take the branch, you get the next instruction executed, and return for another input.

Suppose you now enter `1`. `if` is still happy, takes the branch, shows "correct" and waits for another input.

If you then simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> `x` will remain unchanged, so the `correct` branch will be taken.

So what is actually happening is that `x` after <kbd>Enter</kbd> repeats the last input.

To get over this problem, you need to execute

```
set "x="
set /p x=enter the password:
```

which clears `x` first. The `set "var=value"` syntax ensures that any trailing spaces on the batch line are not included in the value assigned to `var`.

You can use this characteristic to assign a default value,

```
set "x=hello"
set /p x=enter the password:
```

would set `x` to `hello` if the user simply replies <kbd>Enter</kbd> to your prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if %x%==1
```

To this:

```
if "%x%" EQU "1"
```

The quotes encase the variable so you always have a valid string to compare, then you have to do the same to what you're comparing it to for consistency.  `EQU` is another way to compare strings (check out `if /?` for other operators).