# Batch Else Statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

im making a game in batch because its simple, and i was trying to write a else statment, but ive figured out i can only use 1 else in every class, so only 1 input will work but i need multipul to work

```
cls
color 02
ECHO Welcome to your hacking console, you can type main to get back to the main menu

set /p input=Command:

if %input%==main (
goto main
) else (
goto error
)
if %input%==tracert (
goto tracert
) else (
goto error
)
if %input%==IPlookup (
goto IPlookup
) else (
goto error
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an else - you just want to do something if none of the other if statements do something:

```
cls
color 02
ECHO Welcome to your hacking console, you can type main to get back to the main menu
set /p input=Command:
if %input%==main goto main
if %input%==tracert goto tracert
if %input%==IPlookup goto IPlookup
goto error
```

Comment: I would recomend adding `"` between your variables.  saves the chance of crashes.  read more on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418771/batch-set-p-crashes-when-no-input?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have only one command after an if statement, you can just post it afterwards.  I know Jerry had a great answer, but I just felt like adding more detail.

If I needed to perform multiple tasks, the `(` would be very helpful.  here's an example:

```
if %x%==1 (
:: do some stuff
:: do more stuff
:: do even more stuff
)
```

But if I only need to `do some stuff`, I would just put it in one line.

```
if %x%==1 :: do some stuff
```

Since in your script, you are jumping to another label, once you hit that if statement, your away from that part of the script..  Here's what I mean:

```
if %x%==1 goto label_01
echo this won't get displayed unless %x% isn't equal to "1"

:label_01
echo anything after the "if" line wont get displayed, since we are here.
```

And since batch scripts are read by cmd.exe from left to right, and top to bottom, we can stack up those `if` statements.

```
if %x%==1 goto label_01
if %x%==2 goto label_02
if %x%==3 goto label_03
:: we now know that %x% is not equal to 1, 2, or three.  so now we can take advantage of that and post some script.
:: do some stuff
```

Since your script seems to be based off of a menu system, I recommend changing it up a bit:

```
cls
color 02
ECHO Welcome to your hacking console!
echo.
echo Press 1 to     go back to the main menu
echo Press 2 to     Tracerout
echo Press 3 to     Lookup IP address
choice /c 123 >nul
set input=%errorlevel%
if %input%==1 goto main
if %input%==2 goto tracert
if %input%==3 goto IPlookup
```

This method saves us the need to `goto error`.  It also saves time, because now instead of typing out a whole word, you just type a number.  If you type an unsupported number, nothing will happen.

Of course, this method won't work if your on XP.

BTW, a hacking machine?  I remember scripting a couple of these.  Except mine had the options of a DOS attack, and a browser password extractor :)

Comment: I always compile my batch files, and my compiler screws up the errorlevel like in a .cmd file.  That's why I set the variable %input% to errorlevel, because that very same if statement will reset the errorlevel.  Either way, this will still work.